# Extract a specific pattern in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I need to extract a specific value (release version in my case) from a string. I don't know how regex work in Ansible. Below is my Play -

```
---
 - name: Getting the status of current deployment
   stat:
     path: /opt/tomcat/apps/myapp
   register: p

 - debug:
     msg: "The value of symlink is {{ p.stat.lnk_target }}"

 - debug:
     msg: "{{ p.stat.lnk_target.split('/')[4]}}"
```

Output:

```
Getting the status of current deployment...
Monday 18 May 2020  11:18:43 +0100 (0:00:01.580)       0:00:01.812 ************
  server1 ok
set_fact...
Monday 18 May 2020  11:18:43 +0100 (0:00:00.552)       0:00:02.364 ************
  server1 ok
debug...
Monday 18 May 2020  11:18:43 +0100 (0:00:00.077)       0:00:02.442 ************
  server1 ok: {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "The value of symlink is /app/tomcat/releases/Release1.40.0-07/myapp/webapp"
}
debug...
Monday 18 May 2020  11:35:20 +0100 (0:00:00.080)       0:00:02.234 ************
  myvm-kn-u1 ok: {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Release1.40.0-07"
}
```

I want to extract the release number from it and put it in a variable. For example in the above output it is **1.40.0-07**

Let me know if someone can guide. Tried to look into google but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Is the string fixed? can you split based on / and get the version?

Comment: @CiroRa Ok I have tried it and now getting the above result. I have updated the question. Now the value i am getting using split is Release1.40.0-07 but I actually need only the number part. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is use `regex_replace`

In your case

```
- debug:
     msg: "{{ p.stat.lnk_target.split('/')[4] | regex_replace('^Release(.*)$', '\\1') }}"
```

May be you need to adjust the Regex little bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to [`reject`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#reject) the alphabet part. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ p.stat.lnk_target.split('/')[4]|
                 reject('match', '[a-zA-Z]')|join() }}"
```

also [`regex_replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters)

```yaml
    - debug:
         msg: "{{ p.stat.lnk_target.split('/')[4]|
                  regex_replace(my_regex, my_replace) }}"
      vars:
        my_regex: '^Release(.*)$'
        my_replace: '\1'
```

gives the same result

```yaml
    "msg": "1.40.0-07"
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses. Below regex worked for me -
` 
- debug:
     msg: "{{ p.stat.lnk_target.split('/')[4] | regex_replace('^Release(.*)$', '\\1') }}" 
`

Comment: Right. The group must be double-escaped `'\\1'` when inside of double-quoted string "{{ ... }}". See [7.3.1. Double-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2787109) vs. [7.3.2. Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097).

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Happy to hear that it's working. I think my answer is the one needs to be accepted though. LOL thanks

Comment: @Sam LOL okay. yeah you were the first one to guide me in the right direction and then Vladimir gave the exact answer. I have accepted yours. :)